# Scala two varying size list concatenate based on condition

Tags: list, scala, foreach, collections

I'm new to scala and trying to concatenate two varying size list based on condition,
Below are the lists,

```
val check1:String = "NULL||BLANK||LENGTH"
val check2:String = "LENGTH||DUPLICATE"
val check3:String = "NUMERIC"
val checkLists = List(check1,check2,check3)

checkLists: List[String] = List(NULL||BLANK||LENGTH, LENGTH||DUPLICATE, NUMERIC)

val condList = List(">=2","<7")
```

I'm trying to concatenate checkLists & condList based on condition and create new list, whenever List contains String "LENGTH" it should concatenated with condList like below

```
List(NULL||BLANK||LENGTH~>=2, LENGTH~<7||DUPLICATE, NUMERIC)
```

I can able to use zip, foreach and case to concatenate of two equal size lists but here I'm facing trouble with different size lists.

Comment: `zipAll` will cope with lists of different length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zipAll` will give the answer you are looking for:

```
checkLists.zipAll(condList, "", "").map {
  case (check, cond) => check.replaceAll("LENGTH", "LENGTH~" + cond)
}

List(NULL||BLANK||LENGTH~>=2, LENGTH~<7||DUPLICATE, NUMERIC)
```

The missing element of `condList` is given as `""`, but a different default condition could be used if required.

Note that if the second `LENGTH` string is in the third element of `checkLists` rather than the second element, it will not get any condition. This may or may not be what is required.

Comment: Thanks Tim for letting me to know about zipAll! I changed my code to get static list elements for cond list.